# leafletProxy to change map with fixed fillOpacity in addPolygons, Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I made a Shiny app with Year slider so that the map could update the value by Year with `leafletProxy`.

However, if I set `fillOpacity` less than 1 in `addPolygons`. The opacity from the next Year would overlay on the previous display. So one after one, it would fully be opaque. I could add `clearShapes()` after `proxy %>%`  to overcome this, but the shape would be re-drawn and I could see the refresh.

With `fillOpacity = 1`, this would not be a problem, but the color is just too bright.

The first graph below is the initial view, and the second one is after sliding by one year.

Is there anyways to fix `fillOpacity` for each update without `clearShapes()`?

The parts of my codes for this are:

```
    observe({
        df <- mapSelected()
        value <- as.numeric(displayValue())
        proxy <- leafletProxy("mapPlot", session, data = df)
        proxy %>% 
            addPolygons(fillColor = ~regionPal()(value), fill = TRUE,
                        fillOpacity = 0.6,
                        color = 'white', weight = 1, opacity = 0.8,
                        popup = paste(mapLevel(), ": ", df[[SAName()]], "<br>",
                                      "ED counts: ", value),
                        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = 'white',
                                                            weight = 3,
                                                            opacity = 1,
                                                            bringToFront = FALSE))
    })
    
    output$mapPlot <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            fitBounds(lng1 = 140.99926, lng2 = 153.63873,
                      lat1 = -37.50508, lat2 = -28.15702)
    })
```

[image][image]